# How to authenticate ansible managed node using cyberark password

Tags: authentication, ansible, managed, cyber-ark

I'm having 1000 + RHEL 6/7 servers integrated with cyberark, the local user's (sudo user - remote user as per Ansible control node) is fetching password from my cyberark and it gets refreshed every 8 hours. Can you please suggest procedure to authenticate and execute my playbooks on the managed nodes using cyberark password.

Comment: By using the dedicated [`cyberark_credential` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cyberark/pas/cyberark_credential_module.html)?

Comment: I saw that but I'm not able to write a play / tasks, to fetch managed node password to run any tasks. Can you please help on this.. with any reference short tasks

Comment: SO works the other way arround. You should edit your question, show what you have tried so far and describe your exact problem. To put you on track a very basic and totally untested outline playbook: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/05725563e3eabd17e7170d491038ed1a

Comment: I have just tried, exactly the one mentioned in the ansible-doc but in my server that module is not available as I use 2.7. Will try this in different version and keep you posted.

Comment: @pugazhendhi What did you do with this case?, share you solution, cheers

Comment: There were no progress in that. I'm still dead struck and not finding any proper solutions or articles to authenticate.